# 2008 Pontiac G5 Coolant is starting to run hot when driving. Slowly climbs to 225-230

Tags: coolant, overheating

Just wanting to know what a possible diagnosis could be on why it is starting to overheat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be a few things:

1. Low coolant
2. Failing water pump (or slipping belt)
3. Sticking thermostat
4. Obstructed passages in the radiator
5. Cooling system not holding pressure (rad cap not sealing, cracked rad, leak somewhere, bad head gasket)

Comment: Or all of the above.

Comment: Or any combination, as well.